# Training and Testing alphabets don't match issue, in making MaxEnt using Mallet

Tags: java, mallet, maxent

I am new to Mallet and using it for making a MaxEnt model. What I want to achieve is I wanted to classify a text in some categories. (Using sample names for categories) I have my training data in a folder named as `fruits_training_data` which have 4 files:

```
apples.txt
bananas.txt
oranges.txt
mangoes.txt
```

First I imported this data in mallet using this command.

```
bin\mallet import-dir --input fruits_training_data --output fruits_training.mallet
```

I had also test data for each category in separate folder and in separate files. It's hierarchy is also same. Folder name is `fruits_testing_data`. It has same file names as training folder. Same thing I did with test data.

```
bin\mallet import-dir --input fruits_testing_data --output fruits_testing.mallet
```

Then I am making MaxEnt model using this command.

```
bin\mallet train-classifier --training-file fruits_training.mallet --testing-file fruits_testing.mallet --trainer MaxEnt --report test:accuracy
```

This is giving me an error as:

> Training and testing alphabets don't match!
>   at cc.mallet.classify.tui.Vectors2Classify.main(Vectors2Classify.java:27
>   5)

I searched this and did not find any help until now. Can someone help me to figure out at which step I am doing mistake? Will be thankful to you.